# Citing multiple references with llncs

Tags: bibtex, lncs

I am trying to cite two references with the llncs style, but the second comes up as a "?". Any ideas?

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\begin{document}

\cite{her1, her2}

\bibliographystyle{splncs03}
\bibliography{paper}
\end{document}
```

And in paper.bib:

```
@article {her1,
    title = {Generating structured music for bagana using quality metrics based on Markov models},
    journal = {Expert Systems With Applications},
    volume = {in press},
    year = {2015},
    author = {D. Herremans and S. Weisser and K. S{\"o}rensen and D. Conklin}
}
article {her2,
    title = {Classification and generation of composer-specific music using global feature models and variable neighborhood search},
    journal = {Computer Music Journal},
    volume = {in press},
    year = {2015},
    author = {D. Herremans and K. S{\"o}rensen and David Martens}
}
```

Comes up as: [1,?]  (both references separately do work)

Is there another command I should use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This work when you add

```
\usepackage{cite}
```

Comment: I think it also works if you do not use a space after comma in cite. \cite{her1,her2}

Answer (score 3):

It seems that LNCS is misinterpreting any blank space inside the `\cite{ }` command as part of the reference. According to this, neither `\cite{ her1 }` is working.

The correct way of doing it is **removing all blank spaces** from the citation, like in

```latex
\cite{her1,her2}
```